# How to print UserInfo with google Oauth2.0 in Php

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, openid, google-api-php-client, userinfo

How can I print UserInfo with the latest version of google Oauth 2.0 
 if 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile scope is deprecated

"**google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php**" Folder doesn't exist anymore

I want to print username, email ...

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :
replace scopes with Userinfo like  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile

with that  :

`$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login");
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read");`

And It Works !

Answer (score 0):

The `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile` scope was replaced with the `profile` scope so your client should request the latter.

Comment: But how to access to the lastname, firstname is it some sort of Array ?

Comment: you can access `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me` with a proper credential and then a JSON object is returned that contains so-called claims as in `{
    "displayName": "John Jones",
    "name": {
        "familyName": "Jones",
        "givenName": "John"
    },
}` so you'd access lastname as `$response["name"]["familyName"]`